# MYSQL Complex order by two columns mixing results

Tags: mysql

I have table `products` like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `products` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` longtext,
  `place` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

+----+---------------------+---------+-------+
| id |      created_at     |   name  | place |
+----+---------------------+---------+-------+
|  1 | 2000-01-01 17:00:00 | Ninth   |   0   |
|  2 | 2000-01-01 14:00:00 | Second  |   2   |
|  3 | 2000-01-01 19:00:00 | Sixth   |   0   |
|  4 | 2000-01-01 18:00:00 | Eighth  |   0   |
|  5 | 2000-01-01 15:00:00 | First   |   1   |
|  6 | 2000-01-01 16:00:00 | Tenth   |   0   |
|  7 | 2000-01-01 20:00:00 | Seventh |   7   |
|  8 | 2000-01-01 21:00:00 | Fifth   |   0   |
|  9 | 2000-01-01 23:00:00 | Fourth  |   4   |
| 10 | 2000-01-01 22:00:00 | Third   |   0   |
+----+---------------------+---------+-------+
```

I'm looking to order it like this:

```
+----+---------------------+---------+-------+
| id |      created_at     |   name  | place |
+----+---------------------+---------+-------+
|  5 | 2000-01-01 15:00:00 | First   |   1   |
|  2 | 2000-01-01 14:00:00 | Second  |   2   |
|  9 | 2000-01-01 23:00:00 | Third   |   0   |
|  7 | 2000-01-01 20:00:00 | Fourth  |   4   |
| 10 | 2000-01-01 22:00:00 | Fifth   |   0   |
|  8 | 2000-01-01 21:00:00 | Sixth   |   0   |
|  3 | 2000-01-01 19:00:00 | Seventh |   7   |
|  4 | 2000-01-01 18:00:00 | Eighth  |   0   |
|  1 | 2000-01-01 17:00:00 | Ninth   |   0   |
|  6 | 2000-01-01 16:00:00 | Tenth   |   0   |
+----+---------------------+---------+-------+
```

Order by `place` asc without '0', filling missing `place`s with records ordered by `created_at` desc.

My best is:

```
select * from products order by `place` = 0,  `place` asc, created_at desc;
```

But this don't fill missing `place`s.

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/77d49e/2)

Comment: I'm looking for scalable answer, my actual `products` table have 123913 records with random names.

Comment: Closer then this result i could not come http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/77d49e/49 .. You ORDER BY question is to complex for SQL to handle.. advice you to update the place with a number

Answer (score 2):

Use ORDER BY CASE clauses. 
Like so.

**Query**

```
SELECT 
 *
FROM 
 products
ORDER BY 
 CASE
  WHEN products.name = 'First'
  THEN 1

  WHEN products.name = 'Second'
  THEN 2

  WHEN products.name = 'Third'
  THEN 3  

  WHEN products.name = 'Fourth'
  THEN 4

  WHEN products.name = 'Fifth'
  THEN 5

  WHEN products.name = 'Sixth'
  THEN 6

  WHEN products.name = 'Seventh'
  THEN 7

  WHEN products.name = 'Eighth'
  THEN 8

  WHEN products.name = 'Ninth'
  THEN 9

  WHEN products.name = 'Tenth'
  THEN 10

 END
```

**Result**

```
| id |           created_at |    name | place |
|----|----------------------|---------|-------|
|  5 | 2000-01-01T15:00:00Z |   First |     1 |
|  2 | 2000-01-01T14:00:00Z |  Second |     2 |
| 10 | 2000-01-01T22:00:00Z |   Third |     0 |
|  9 | 2000-01-01T23:00:00Z |  Fourth |     4 |
|  8 | 2000-01-01T21:00:00Z |   Fifth |     0 |
|  3 | 2000-01-01T19:00:00Z |   Sixth |     0 |
|  7 | 2000-01-01T20:00:00Z | Seventh |     7 |
|  4 | 2000-01-01T18:00:00Z |  Eighth |     0 |
|  1 | 2000-01-01T17:00:00Z |   Ninth |     0 |
|  6 | 2000-01-01T16:00:00Z |   Tenth |     0 |
```

demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/77d49e/11

Comment: I'm looking for scalable answer, my actual `products` table have 123913 records with random names.

Answer (score 0):

This will work, not sure if is the best solution, but give it a try,

Create a table where you specify the order you want, something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ordering` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  `name` longtext,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

INSERT INTO `ordering` ( `id`, `name`) VALUES 
( '1', 'First' ), 
( '2', 'Second'), 
( '3', 'Third' ), 
( '4', 'Fourth' ), 
( '5', 'Fifth' ), 
( '6', 'Sixth' ), 
( '7', 'Seventh' ), 
( '8', 'Eighth' ), 
( '9', 'Ninth' ), 
( '10', 'Tenth' );
```

And then just join it with your other table like this:

```
select p.* from products p 
left join ordering o on o.name = p.name
order by o.id asc
```

Also if you do that, it will be better to update your product schema and replace your product.name by prodcut.orderId or something like this, but this is up to you

you can see the result on this [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dc640a/1)

Answer (score 0):

Why not fill missing `place` fields? Something like

```
update products set place=3 where name='Third';
update products set place=5 where name='Fifth';
.......
```

Comment: I cant hardcode names like this, in my actual table they are random, the logic is that missing places is filling with records with place = 0 and order by created_at desc

Comment: reassign places for all records in table when 1 place is changing seems not so good, but thanks anyway